# How to require a different node module client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify, i18next

I'm trying to internationalize an isomorphic react app using [i18next](http://i18next.com/). While getting it to work server-side was no big deal, it fails client-side, telling me `fs.readFile is not a function`. As far as I understand, in order to use i18next in the browser (with browserify), you need to require `i18next-client`, which means, that I would need to `require` a different node module on the server than on the client. After some research I still have absolutely no idea how to get this done and am asking myself if I understand something completely wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `process.browser` which is only defined browser-side when using Browserify.

```
var i18n = process.browser ? require('i18next-client') : require('i18next');
```